# how to chech whether a file in a ssh server is empty or not using php

Tags: php, file, ssh

I am connecting to a `SSH server` using `PHP` and there is **file called difference** in the server.
I want to check whether it is empty or not and echo something depending on the result.

I am aware of the function :

```
file_get_contents("./difference")
```

But this will work in in the `localhost` directory. I want to check in the SSH server. 
How Should i proceed...?

PS : I use **ssh2** to connect to ssh server

Comment: The answer will depend on what technique you use to connect to the ssh server, so you'll need to tell us about that.

Comment: i use ssh2 to connect to the ssh server

Comment: ssh connection to a shell, or just an ssh-protected pipe? If it's a shell, then the equivalent of `ssh user@remote.host 'stat /path/to/difference.txt'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this ways :

1) use ssh2.sftp protocol :

```
$data  = file_get_contents('ssh2.sftp://user:pass@youraddress.com:22/path/to/one/file');
```

2) use ssh2

```
$ssh2_conn = ssh2_connect('youraddress.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($ssh2_conn, 'username', 'password');
$sftp_conn = ssh2_sftp($ssh2_conn);
$file_stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sftp_conn/path/to/one/file", 'r');
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try:

```
if (0 == filesize($path_to_difference)){
echo "File is empty!";
} else {
echo "File has data inside!";
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no it will check in current directory no in the ssh server

Comment: Oh so you would like to execute a unix command to check this? Like you use PHP to enter in the unix command?